# Update table equalize where same id but different country

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem creating an SQL statement that would run in a cronjob every few minutes.

I want to equalize one column where `ItemCode`s (IDs) are the same but each country is different

Table:

```
+----------+--------+---------+

| ItemCode | OnHand | country |

+----------+--------+---------+

| 08040    | 450    | de      |

+----------+--------+---------+

| 08040    | 000    | hu      |

+----------+--------+---------+

| 08040    | 145    | si      |

+----------+--------+---------+
```

I want to take `OnHand where country = de` and put it in `OnHand where country = hu`. (for multiple `ItemCode` - have 7000 of them)

```
UPDATE sap_items
    ON sap_items.ItemCode = sap_items.ItemCode AND
       sap_items.country='de'
SET sap_items.OnHand = sap_items.OnHand
WHERE sap_items.country='hu'";
```

I understand that this is wrong. But i'm not sure how to properly put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current syntax is off.  You could do an `UPDATE` combined with a self join:

```
UPDATE sap_items AS t1
INNER JOIN sap_items AS t2
    ON t1.ItemCode = t2.ItemCode
SET t1.OnHand = t2.OnHand
WHERE t1.country = 'hu' AND t2.country = 'de'
```

Comment: Its working! thank you very much. And yes my syntax is really bad. Do you have any recommendation on where to start learning? And what is the best way to get into it?

Comment: To be honest with you, Stack Overflow is a great place to learn.  TechOnTheNet is also a very good resource.